# Use concat and maintain length of variable

Tags: mysql, concatenation, variable-length

I'm trying to use concat on some variables. These variables have been declared as chars:

```
declare v_order_date char(10);
declare v_quantity char(11);
declare v_plant char(100);
```

I have a cursor where I am setting these as some outputs.  To call the results, I am setting v_msg as

```
set v_msg := concat( v_msg, '\n', v_order_date, v_quantity, v_plant);
```

However, the result I am getting when I select v_msg is:

```
2012-01-222501008 Creeping Buttercup
```

but I want to maintain the length of the declared variables in my select that looks like this

```
2012-01-22  250    1008    Creeping Buttercup
```

Are there any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Do not confuse maximum column length for some sort of "variable length." You want to pad each value to the maximum column length before concatenating. In a language with `printf` you could do this with a "simple" format specifier; I'm not sure of the idiomatic way to do this with SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL `repeat()` and `char_length()`

```
set v_msg := concat(v_msg, '\n', v_order_date, repeat(' ', 10-char_length(v_order_date)), '\n',  v_quantity, repeat(' ', 11-char_length(v_quantity)), '\n' , v_plant);
```